# Spring JPA save(T) generate StackOverFlow

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, gson, stack-overflow

I have an entity that has the following format:

```
@Entity
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {
  @Id
  private String uuid;
  private String name;

  @ManyToOne
  @NotNull
  private CompanyEntity company;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userGroupIdentifier.userEntity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Set<UserGroupEntity> groups;

}
```

If I transform the userEntity into userDTO (it doesn't have the groups attribute but it has the company attribute), modify the userDTO and transform the data from userDTO to userEntity and do a save(userEntity), it works correctly.

But, if I transform the userDTO to a JSON with the Gson library (to save the object in a Redis cache) and then transform the JSON->userDTO->userEntity and do the save(userEntity), it returns a stackOverFlow:

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError

I have compared the object and apparently it has the same data.

What could be happening?

Stacktrace: https://sharetext.me/w3ifhkpf0h

Comment: Can you please post the whole stacktrace. There you will find where the StackOverflow comes from

Comment: Hi @SimonMartinelli the website wouldn't let me put it because it reached the character limit: https://sharetext.me/w3ifhkpf0h

Comment: There is likely to be recursive relationship between your entities i.e. `UserEntity` referencing some `UserGroupEntity`s in the set and then each `UserGroupEntity` referencing `UserEntity`. This creates recursive object references which means it is likely to lead to stackoverflow when mapping/persisting. Post all three of your related entities and check if you have toString and hashcode methods for each of them. You will need to exclude the non-owning side entity from toString and hashcode implementation.

Comment: Thanks @Setu! I have solved it